# Can a process share unused memory with others?

Tags: process, memory, java, shared-memory

I want to run about 200 processes with my experiments. Every of them really needs less than *a GB*:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
24688 rinkman   20   0 6082416 335536  15680 S 116.9  0.3  77:32.92 java
25314 rinkman   20   0 6614936 379040  15700 S 116.6  0.4  73:43.02 java
25780 rinkman   20   0 6082408 348140  15664 S 116.6  0.4  72:12.34 java
25994 rinkman   20   0 6082408 350592  15656 S 114.6  0.4  71:42.34 java
30472 rinkman   20   0 6749092 441492  15664 S 108.6  0.4  64:54.38 java
27052 rinkman   20   0 6548364 403040  15692 S 106.3  0.4  66:38.30 java
29314 rinkman   20   0 6022012 393656  15660 S 105.0  0.4  65:57.09 java
28173 rinkman   20   0 6681492 427816  15660 S 104.3  0.4  66:17.47 java
```

I have the access to 6 nodes with *100 GB* of RAM per each of them. So if they take only *a GB*, there were no problems. But, as you see above, every one takes more than *6 GB*.

I was very surprised when I looked at the output of `free -m`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          96481       15396         326          75       80758       80448
Swap:         16383        2336       14047
```

It shows only *15.4 GB* used. It led me to a thought, can processes share unused memory? Is *80.4 GB* actually available? Unfortunately, I could not google interesting information. I only stumbled upon articles about multiprocessing/threading with data exchange, common cache &c. Please, could you shed light on this question for me?

**P.S.** If this is impossible, is there any way to decrease allocated memory for these processes (I just ran only 8 from 200)? The problem is in the fact that bash script provides only *2 GB* for **java** (this is a part of):

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx2048m -Djava.library.path="$BEAST_LIB:/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" -cp "$BEAST_LIB/beast.jar:$BEAST_LIB/beast-beagle.jar" dr.app.beast.BeastMain $*
```

So I cannot understand the reason why it always takes *4-5 GB* more. I have the same phenomenon with other Java programmes, for instance, **BEAST 2** or **treeannotator**.

Comment: Yes, but the software should be created for this purpose. Check System V InterProcess Communication System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seemingly reading it wrong.

The first column is `VIRT`, it's inconsequential and in absolute most cases should be ignored completely.

What you're interested in is `RSS` and each of your processes is under half a gig of RAM. You're doing fine.

Now on to your question.

There's no such thing as sharing "unused" memory, it's either used or not used. Some memory is indeed shared and that's the third column called `SHR`. That's the memory of shared libraries. If I'm not mistaken the Linux kernel has long stopped calculating/showing the right value for it because it's very complicated.

P.S. To be honest I've no idea why Linux RAM utilities (`top`, `htop`, `free`, etc.) show the VIRT column. I've never used or paid attention to it, or seen anyone do that.

Comment: The sole practical using `VIRT` for me is to look at maximum possible allocated memory for **java** process (*VIRT* - *the aforementioned 4-5 GB*) if I ran it a long time ago & do not remember :-)